# What is the difference between gz topic and rostopic?

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am playing around in gazebo and noticed there seems to be some distinction between ROS topics and Gazebo topics. Can anyone explain the difference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298640/what-is-the-difference-between-gz-topic-and-rostopic?/) by [Cler](https://answers.ros.org/users/36657/cler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate of [gazebosim.org#q15789](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15789/relations-of-gz-topic-rostopic-and-how-to-check-the-information-of-a-gz-topic-message-typelike-mav_msgsmsgscommandmotorspeed/).

`rostopic` connects to [ROS Master](http://wiki.ros.org/Master). `gz` command connects to [Gazebo Master](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=architecture#GazeboMaster).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1